# Associating a combination's indices with a value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, chemistry

I am working on a program for which I need combinations of the distances between atoms, or various points in 3D space. Here's an example:

A file 'test' contains the following information:

```
Ti 1.0 1.0 1.0

O 0.0 2.0 0.0

O 0.0 0.0 0.0

Ti 1.0 3.0 4.0

O 2.0 5.0 0.0
```

I would like my code to compute all combinations of distances between the points (which I've done!), then, I need to count the number of times that the distance between one atom and another is less than 2.2.

That's confusing in words, so I'll show you what I've got so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, math, scipy, itertools
import numpy as np

try:
    infile = sys.argv[1]

except:
    print "Needs file name"
    sys.exit(1)

#opening files for first part
ifile = open(infile, 'r')
coordslist = []

#Creating a file of just coordinates that can be 'mathed on'
for line in ifile:
    pair = line.split()
    atom = (pair[0]); x = float(pair[1]); y = float(pair[2]); z = float(pair[3])
    coordslist += [(x,y,z)]
ifile.close()

#Define distance
def distance(p0,p1):
    return math.sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p0[1] - p1[1])**2 + (p0[2] - p1[2])**                                          2)

#Initializing for next section
dislist = []
bondslist = []

#Compute distances between all points 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, etc.
for p0, p1 in itertools.combinations(coordslist,2):
    print p0, p1, distance(p0,p1)
    dislist += [distance(p0, p1)]
    if distance(p0,p1) < 2.2:
        bondslist += [(p0, distance(p0,p1))]
print bondslist
print dislist
```

I wasn't sure if making these lists would help me or not. So far, they haven't.

The output is:

```
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (0.0, 2.0, 0.0) 1.73205080757

(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) 1.73205080757

(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (1.0, 3.0, 4.0) 3.60555127546

(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (2.0, 5.0, 0.0) 4.24264068712

(0.0, 2.0, 0.0) (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) 2.0

(0.0, 2.0, 0.0) (1.0, 3.0, 4.0) 4.24264068712

(0.0, 2.0, 0.0) (2.0, 5.0, 0.0) 3.60555127546

(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) (1.0, 3.0, 4.0) 5.09901951359

(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) (2.0, 5.0, 0.0) 5.38516480713

(1.0, 3.0, 4.0) (2.0, 5.0, 0.0) 4.58257569496

[((1.0, 1.0, 1.0), 1.7320508075688772), ((1.0, 1.0, 1.0), 1.7320508075688772), ((0.0, 2.0, 0.0), 2.0)]

[1.7320508075688772, 1.7320508075688772, 3.605551275463989, 4.242640687119285, 2.0, 4.242640687119285, 3.605551275463989, 5.0990195135927845, 5.385164807134504, 4.58257569495584]
```

One thing I need from this output is the number of times each atom has a distance less than 2.2, for example:

```
1 2 (because atom 1 has two distances less than 2.2 associated with it)

2 2

3 2 

4 0

5 0
```

I *also* need to see what two atoms are making that less-than-2.2 distance. I'm doing this to calculate Pauling charges; this is where you need to look at an atom, determine how many bonds there are to it (atoms less than 2.2 angstroms away), then look at the atoms *attached* to that atom, and see how many atoms are attached to *those*. It's terribly frustrating, but it's all going to be dependent on keeping track of each atom instead of just their combinations. An array will probably be extremely useful.

I've checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150990/python-itertools-combinations-how-to-obtain-the-indices-of-the-combined-numbers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays) for help and I think I need to combine these methods in some way. Any help is unbelievably appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we begin, let me note that in case of crystals (and I have a bit of a suspicion that you're not dealing with a Ti2O3 *molecule*) you should be careful with the periodic boundary conditions, i.e. the two last atoms that are distant from everyone might be closer to an atom in a neighbouring cell.

What you're trying to do is very simple if you know what tools to use. You're looking for a method that will tell you the *pairwise distance* between all the points in a set. The function that does this is called `pdist`, [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) to be precise. This can compute pairwise distance for arbitrary sets of points in any dimensions, with any kind of distance. In your specific case, the default Euclidean distance will do.

The pair-wise matrix distance of a set of points (with element `[i,j]` telling you the distance between points `i` and `j`) is symmetric by construction, with zeros in the diagonal. For this reason the usual implementations of `pdist` return only the off-diagonal elements on one side of the diagonal, and `scipy`'s version is no exception. However, there's the handy [`scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html#scipy.spatial.distance.squareform) function that will turn an array containing such a condensed version of a purely off-diagonal symmetrical matrix, and makes it full. From there it's easy to post-process.

Here's what I'd do:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial as ssp

# atoms and positions:
# Ti 1.0 1.0 1.0
# O  0.0 2.0 0.0
# O  0.0 0.0 0.0
# Ti 1.0 3.0 4.0
# O  2.0 5.0 0.0

# define positions as m*n array, where n is the dimensionality (3)
allpos = np.array([[1.,1,1],  # 1. is lazy for dtype=float64
                   [0,2,0], 
                   [0,0,0],
                   [1,3,4],
                   [2,5,0]])

# compute pairwise distances
alldist_condensed = ssp.distance.pdist(allpos)       # vector of off-diagonal elements on one side
alldist = ssp.distance.squareform(alldist_condensed) # full symmetric distance matrix

# set diagonals to nan (or inf) to avoid tainting our output later
fancy_index = np.arange(alldist.shape[0])
alldist[fancy_index,fancy_index] = np.nan

# find index of "near" neighbours
thresh = 2.2
neighbslist = [np.where(alldist[k,:]<thresh)[0] for k in range(alldist.shape[0])]  # the k'th element is an array containing the indices which are "close" to atom number k

# find total number of "near" neighbours
nearnum = [neighbs.size for neighbs in neighbslist] # the k'th element is the number of atoms which are "close" to atom number k
```

So for your specific case, `alldist` contains the full distance matrix:

```
array([[        nan,  1.73205081,  1.73205081,  3.60555128,  4.24264069],
       [ 1.73205081,         nan,  2.        ,  4.24264069,  3.60555128],
       [ 1.73205081,  2.        ,         nan,  5.09901951,  5.38516481],
       [ 3.60555128,  4.24264069,  5.09901951,         nan,  4.58257569],
       [ 4.24264069,  3.60555128,  5.38516481,  4.58257569,         nan]])
```

As you can see, I manually set the diagonal elements to `np.nan`. This is necessary since I'm intending to check the elements of this matrix that are less than `thresh`, and the zeros in the diagonal would surely qualify. In our case `np.inf` would have been an equally good choice for these elements, but then what if you wanted to get points that are *further* from each other than `thresh`? Clearly for that case `-np.inf` or `np.nan` would be acceptable (so I went with the latter).

The post-processing of near neighbours leads us out of the realm of numpy (you should always stick with numpy as long as you can, that's usually fastest). For each atom you want to get a list of those atoms that are near it. Well, this is not an object with constant length for each atom, so you can't store this nicely in an array. The logical conclusion is to use a `list`, but then you can go all python and use a list comprehension to construct this list (reminder from above):

```
neighbslist = [np.where(alldist[k,:]<thresh)[0] for k in range(alldist.shape[0])]  # the k'th element is an array containing the indices which are "close" to atom number k
```

Here `np.where` will find the indices within row `k` for which the distance is small enough, and the 1d array of indices is stored in the `k`th element of the resulting list `neighbslist`. Then it's trivial to check the length of these arrays for each atom, giving you your "number of near neihbours" list. Note that we could've cast the output of `np.where` to a `list` in the list comp to leave numpy entirely, but then we would have had to use `len(neighbs)` instead of `neighbs.size` in the next line.

So, you have two key variables, two lists to be precise; `nearnum[k]` is the number of "near" neighbours for atom `k` (with `k` in `range(allpos.shape[0])`, and `neighbslist[k]` is a 1d numpy array listing the near indices for atom `k`, so `neighbslist[k][j]` (for `j` in `range(nearnum[k])`) is a number in `range(allpos.shape[0])` not equal to `k`. Come to think of it, this list-of-arrays construction is probably a bit ugly, so you should probably cast this object to a proper list of lists during construction (even if this means a bit of overhead).

---

I only noticed at the end that your input data is in a file. Not to worry, that can also be readily read using numpy! Assuming that those empty lines are not in your input name `test`, you can call

```
allpos = np.loadtxt('test',usecols=(1,2,3))
```

to read the position matrix into your variable. The `usecols` option lets `numpy` ignore the first column of the data, which is not numeric, and would cause problems. We don't really need that anyway.

Comment: This was incredibly clear and helpful! I finished my code thanks to you :) I did see pdist but for some reason dismissed it and didn't think it'd serve my purpose. Once I implemented this I was able to construct some nested for loops to loop over the k values and then loop over the values in each nearnum[k] as well. You are a lifesaver. I need to get better at numpy!

Comment: @jd423 I'm very glad I could help:) Numpy is wonderful (but of course you always have to know when to stop, because there are many things that it's not cut out for).

Comment: that's true! Do you know of a similar way to do this but instead of distance, computing a q1q2/r (Coulomb interaction)? And filling out a numpy array with these values akin to filling out one with distance values? The Scipy documentation doesn't seem to include a package like this, but perhaps I'd have to define a function to be used.

Comment: @jd423 if you mean turning "compute for each pair the distance r" into "compute for each pair the Coulomb potential q1q2/r", the answer is `pdist`:) Just use a non-default distance function. Looking at the manual, at first I though it would be possible to pass that function to `pdist` as a custom metric (but note that this is not a metric in the mathematical sense, so you would definitely have to check if it works). But using something like `pdist(allpos, lambda u,v,Q1=q1,Q2=q2: Q1*Q2/np.linalg.norm(u-v)` would mean that your charges have to be the same for every point. (to be cont.)

Comment: You *might* try adding a fourth dimension that contains the charge, and defining your `lambda` custom function like so: `lambda u,v: u[-1]*v[-1]/np.linalg.norm(u[:-1]-v[:-1])`. If your first three dimensions are the actual coordinates, and the fourth dimension (`allpos[:,-1]` or `allpos[:,3]`) contains the charge, at first glance this might work. As I said, you have to check carefully:) But if something's unclear, let me know, I'll elaborate.

Comment: I think I did it! I made a new numpy array where the first-third columns are the coordinates and the fourth column is the charge for each atom. I called it 'nextarray', and then I put 
`Coulomb = ssp.distance.pdist(nextarray, lambda u,v: u[3]*v[3]/np.linalg.norm(u[:-1]-v[:-1]))`. To be honest, i'm not sure what u[:-1] means, but it _did_ give me the correct values. Then, like before, I put it in a square array!  Thank you for giving me some insight there! I hope I wasn't a bother! Next step is more 'threshold' stuff for the coulomb interactions...

Comment: @jd423 you were a delight, don't worry for a second:) That is indexing for arrays which goes `arr[from:to]` (which is the slice of the array starting with index `from` and up to, but *not* including index `to`). So `arr[:-1]` means "slice of the array `arr` starting from the beginning, ending at element -1 (==the last index)", but due to the non-inclusiveness of the second index, this drops the last value. In other words, for your case `u[:-1]` is equivalent to `u[0:3]`, which is again equivalent to `np.array(u[0],u[1],u[2])`. So we just hacked it so that `u/v` contain both position & charge.

Comment: Oh, I see :) I would move this to chat if I had enough rep but that makes sense! Thank you again - so, so clear and helpful!