# Python itertools.combinations: how to obtain the indices of the combined numbers within the combinations at the same time

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, combinations, python-itertools

According to the question presented here: [Python itertools.combinations: how to obtain the indices of the combined numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150990/python-itertools-combinations-how-to-obtain-the-indices-of-the-combined-numbers), given the following code:

```
import itertools
my_list = [7, 5, 5, 4]

pairs = list(itertools.combinations(my_list , 2))
#pairs = [(7, 5), (7, 5), (7, 4), (5, 5), (5, 4), (5, 4)]

indexes = list(itertools.combinations(enumerate(my_list ), 2)
#indexes = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Is there any way to obtain `pairs` and `indexes` in a single line so I can have a lower complexity in my code (e.g. using `enumerate` or something likewise)?

Comment: Just `zip` the two iterators, rather than consuming them into lists.

Comment: Could you please help me how to do that?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: Thank you. I'm reading to get the solution ASAP.

Comment: with `zip (indexes, pairs)` I can get a single list, but I'd like to know if I can have this without having to call `itertools.combinations` twice

Comment: I don't think the output from your second example is correct, if you're taking combinations of the tuples from enumerate that would be the values *and* their indices, the first item emitted would be `((0, 7), (1, 5))`. What you show would be the output from combinations of the indices alone, e.g. from `range(len(my_list))`.

Comment: Yes. You right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Maf - try this, this is as @jonsharpe suggested earlier, use `zip`:

```py
from pprint import pprint
from itertools import combinations

 my_list = [7, 5, 5, 4]
>>> pprint(list(zip(combinations(enumerate(my_list),2), combinations(my_list,2))))
[(((0, 7), (1, 5)), (7, 5)),
 (((0, 7), (2, 5)), (7, 5)),
 (((0, 7), (3, 4)), (7, 4)),
 (((1, 5), (2, 5)), (5, 5)),
 (((1, 5), (3, 4)), (5, 4)),
 (((2, 5), (3, 4)), (5, 4))]
```

Comment: We were writing at the same time. It seems to be the best solution. I'm going to to choose your answer. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

(Explicit is better than implicit. Simple is better than complex.)
I would use list-comprehension for its flexiblity:

```
list((x, (x[0][1], x[1][1])) for x in list(combinations(enumerate(my_list), 2)))
```

This can be further extended using the likes of `opertor.itemgetter`.

Also, the idea is to run use the iterator only once, so that the method can potentially be applied to other non-deterministic iterators as well, say, an `yield` from `random.choices`.